# Windows command for "ls -Rl * > file.dat"

Tags: linux, windows, ls

What is the windows command for the linux command  "ls -Rl * > file.dat" ?

I know it should involve DIR but which parameters would do the exact same thing as  "ls -Rl * > file.dat"?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir /S > file.dat` will do something *similar* to `ls -Rl`, e.g. will list the contents of the directory and all the subdirectores recursively. But if you need *the exact same thing*, just use the exact same `ls` with the same options on Windows, e.g. taken from Cygwin.